# ternary operator in return - FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
  Widget _buildItems() {
    return id == 0
        ? Column(Text("PAGE 1"))
        : Center(
            Text("PAGE 2"),
          );
  }
```

Hello, above is part my flutter code, and I keep getting below error. Could you please look into it? It looks like my syntax is wrong but I just cant pinpoint to where I'm wrong.

Thanks.

```
        ? Column(Text("PAGE 1"))

                ^

packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:4930:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.

  Column({

  ^^^^^^

/lib/components/challenge_menu.dart:32:17: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.

Try removing the extra positional arguments.

        : Center(

                ^

packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:1984:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.

  const Center({ Key? key, double? widthFactor, double? heightFactor, Widget? child })

        ^^^^^^

/lib/components/challenge_menu.dart:30:12: Error: The getter 'id' isn't defined for the class '_ChallengeMenuState'.

 - '_ChallengeMenuState' is from 'package:osam2021/components/challenge_menu.dart' ('/lib/components/challenge_menu.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'id'.

    return id == 0

           ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

**Column class**

A widget that displays its children in a vertical array.

```
Column(
  children: const <Widget>[
    Text('Deliver features faster'),
    Text('Craft beautiful UIs'),
    Expanded(
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.contain, // otherwise the logo will be tiny
        child: FlutterLogo(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

[for more details](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)

and

****Center class****

A widget that centers its child within itself.

```
Center(
     child: Container()
),
```

*You forgot to use child and children .*

Use both of two widgets together:

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text('Logo'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every column has a required property called children. You have to use that to include any sub-widgets inside a column.

Answer (score 1):

Every Columns have a list of "Children" in your case you directly use Text Widget inside Column, You have to use like this:

```
  Column(
           children:[
                       Text("your text"),
                         .....
                         ]

          )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget _buildItems() {
return( id == 0)
    ? Column(children : [Text("PAGE 1")])
    : Center(child : 
        Text("PAGE 2")
      );
  }
```

I dont know what you are going to do with it, but just fix the error

Answer (score 0):

You missed children in Column, and child in Center widget. You should assign an array of widgets to the children key in Column, and Text() widget to the child key in the Center Widget.

You should've code like this

```
Widget _buildItems() {
  return id == 0
    ? Column(children: [Text("PAGE 1")])
    : Center(child: Text("PAGE 2"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution.

```
  Widget _buildItems(int id) {
    return (id == 0)
        ? Column(
            children: const [
              Text(
                "PAGE 1",
              ),
            ],
          )
        : const Center(
            child: Text(
              "PAGE 2",
            ),
          );
  }
```